# admin on rest: display default value in create form

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

Here I used react-material-responsive-grid to display form in multiple row structure. But this is not issue..

I want to display the default value in text field. I gave default value also, but it is not displaying.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CheckboxGroupInput, BooleanField, Filter, List, Edit, Create, Datagrid, ReferenceField, EditButton, DisabledInput, LongTextInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-material-responsive-grid';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import { TextField, SelectField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

const list = [
    "name1", 
    "name2", 
];


export const PostCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props} >
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <LongTextInput source="body" />

            <Grid>
                {list.map((selectItem) => {
                    return  <Row> 
                            <Col xs={1}>
                                <Field name={selectItem} defaultValue="default value" component={TextField} floatingLabelText="Select" hintText="Select"/>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={1}> <div>{selectItem} </div></Col>  
                        </Row>     
                })}
            </Grid>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `defaultValue` prop is not supported by the redux-form `<Field>` component. It's an *aor implementation* for its `<Input>` components.

But you can try to declare the default values at the instantiation of the redux form, like that :

```
const list = ['name1', 'name2'];
const postDefaultValue = { name1: 'default value', name2: 'default value' };
export const PostCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props} >
        <SimpleForm defaultValue={postDefaultValue}>
        ...
```